# How to remove path from /bin/bash line?

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

Is there a way to hide the path in the CLI line?

Right now I get this:

```
fresh_m2@bloedlvm:/srv/www/vhosts/$
```

I want it like this:

```
fresh_m2@bloedlvm$
```

Because if I go very deep into the folders, then the cursor is already in the middle of the screen:

```
fresh_m2@bloedlvm:/srv/www/vhosts/fresh_m2/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ActionValidator/RemoveAction$
```

The path is already showing at the top in putty, this is enough for me:

[image: putty]

---

~/.bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi

# edfe: ls -lah nach cd ausführen
cd () {
    command cd "$@" && ls -lah
}

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: In your `~/.bashrc` file, do you have something setting the prompt? This would look like an assignment to a variable called `PS1`.

Comment: Yes indeed, there is such a setting. Thank you for the hint. I guess I just have to remove that logic there.

Comment: I added my bashrc

Comment: I find putting a linefeed after the path preferable to dropping it -- so something like `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\n\$ '`

Comment: @Grump, where to add this line?

Comment: Are you aware of the bash `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` feature? see for example [How can I shortern my command line prompt's current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687446/how-can-i-shortern-my-command-line-prompts-current-directory)

Comment: But this does trim the dir, I don't want the dir at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `.bashrc` you posted, remove the `\w` in the lines with PS1 before the `$` sign. Depending on what you want, be sure to delete it in either of the two lines (or both) near the `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then`. If you want to delete it in both, you can use this:

**Before:**

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

**After:**

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h\$ '
fi
```

Note: The changes are only taking effect in the next session.

Note: I also removed the colon and the color codes around `\w` from the first PS1 variable.

(See [in the bash man](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#index-prompting), under the headline "prompting" the escape sequences are described)